# Array of structures in a structure in JNA

Tags: java, jna

My native code is

```
typedef struct driver_config {
    unsigned int dllVersion;
    unsigned int channelCount;
    unsigned int reserved[10];
    ChannelConfig channel[64];
} DriverConfig;
```

In Java my class looks like this

```
public class DriverConfig extends Structure {
    
    public int dllVersion;
    public int channelCount;
    public int[] reserved= new int[10];
    ChannelConfig[] channel = new ChannelConfig[64];
    
    public DriverConfig() {
        super();
        init();     
    }
    
    private void init() {
        for (int i = 0; i < channel.length; i++) {
            channel[i]= new ChannelConfig();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected List<String> getFieldOrder() {
        return Arrays.asList(new String[] { "dllVersion", "channelCount", "reserved" });
    }

    //toString()...
}
```

The method declaration is

```
int getDriverConfig(DriverConfig driverConfig);
```

I tried to access the method like this

```
DriverConfig driverConfig = new DriverConfig();
status = dll.INSTANCE.getDriverConfig(driverConfig);
System.out.println("DriverConfig Status: " + status);
System.out.println(driverConfig.toString());
```

If `channel.length` is replaced with less then 50 the array is initialized correctly but with `channel.length` it did not work. It even did not show any error just nothing.

Comment: Is `channel` supposed to be in the field order?

Comment: I am not sure what it means exactly if something is in getFieldOrder(). First I tried with channel but there was an error then

Comment: And what was the error?

Comment: Structure.getFieldOrder() on class DriverConfig provides too many names [4] ([channel, channelCount, dllVersion, reserved]) to match declared fields [3] ([channelCount, dllVersion, reserved])

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `getFieldOrder()` array does not include the last element (`channel`) of your structure.  I see in your comments that you attempted to do this but received an error because you have not declared it `public`. All elements of your structure must be listed in the `FieldOrder` and also declared `public` so they can be found with reflection.

Also, with JNA 5.x (which you should be using) the `@FieldOrder` annotation is preferred.

You haven't identified the mapping for `ChannelConfig`, but your question title and [this API link matching your structure](https://assets.vector.com/cms/content/products/XL_Driver_Library/Docs/XL_Driver_Library_Manual_EN.pdf) indicate that it is a nested structure array. Structure arrays must be allocated using contiguous memory, either by directly allocating the native memory (`new Memory()`) which requires knowing the structure size, or by using `Structure.toArray()`. Allocating in a loop as you have done will end up with memory for each new structure allocated at possibly/probably non-contiguous locations in native memory.  Given that you state that it appears to work for some values, you might be getting lucky with contiguous allocations, but your behavior is certainly undefined.

Your structure mapping should therefore be:

```
@FieldOrder ({"dllVersion", "channelCount", "reserved", "channel"})
public class DriverConfig extends Structure {
    public int dllVersion;
    public int channelCount;
    public int[] reserved= new int[10];
    public ChannelConfig[] channel = (ChannelConfig[]) new ChannelConfig().toArray(64);
}
```