# What possible reasons could there be for a JVM crash in an application with JNA?

Tags: java, c, jna

I'm looking for possible reasons for a strange issue with JNA. I have a Java application which uses bunch of shared libraries, all self made, programmed by me and my colleague. We are using JNA 5.x to expose the C functions from the SOs to java. (Java 11.20 on Linux). We use Gradle 7.4 to build the Java code, the C code is compiled into SOs with cmake.

The issue is that JVM crashes, when I build the project with Gradle and execute all the tests in sequence. This started to happen, after I've included a unit test that tests a function from one of the libraries. I get the following error:

```
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  SIGSEGV (0xb) at pc=0x00007fa08abac0ef, pid=129694, tid=129697
#
# JRE version: OpenJDK Runtime Environment (Red_Hat-11.0.20.0.8-1.fc38) (11.0.20+8) (build 11.0.20+8)
# Java VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (Red_Hat-11.0.20.0.8-1.fc38) (11.0.20+8, mixed mode, sharing, tiered, compressed oops, g1 gc, linux-amd64)
# Problematic frame:
# C  [libc.so.6+0x990ef]
```

So it must be something within this library or the way I call that particular function from it. What makes the issue hard for me is that when I execute just the one unit test, it is green. No JVM problem, and the results come out as expected.

GDB gives me no real clues either, or at least I can't interpret them. When I debug the gradle process, I can see that the function call was successful in the sense that there are correct results in the return value, but after the return of the function is executed I get a problem in libc.

```
Thread 2 "Test worker" received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x00007fe3948420ef in unlink_chunk (p=p@entry=0x7fe38caedbe0, av=0x7fe38c000030) at malloc.c:1604
1604      if (chunksize (p) != prev_size (next_chunk (p)))                                                                                                                                                                    
(gdb) c
Continuing.

Thread 2 "Test worker" received signal SIGILL, Illegal instruction.
futex_wait (private=0, expected=2, futex_word=0x7fe38c000030) at ../sysdeps/nptl/futex-internal.h:146
Downloading source file /usr/src/debug/glibc-2.37-10.fc38.x86_64/nptl/../sysdeps/nptl/futex-internal.h
146       int err = lll_futex_timed_wait (futex_word, expected, NULL, private);                                                                                                                                               
(gdb) n
0x00007fe394317d10 in crash_handler(int, siginfo_t*, void*) () from /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-11.0.20.0.8-1.fc38.x86_64/lib/server/libjvm.so
(gdb) n
Single stepping until exit from function _ZL13crash_handleriP9siginfo_tPv,
which has no line number information.

Thread 20 "VM Periodic Tas" received signal SIGABRT, Aborted.
[Switching to Thread 0x7fe365fff6c0 (LWP 131363)]
__pthread_kill_implementation (threadid=<optimized out>, signo=signo@entry=6, no_tid=no_tid@entry=0) at pthread_kill.c:44
44            return INTERNAL_SYSCALL_ERROR_P (ret) ? INTERNAL_SYSCALL_ERRNO (ret) : 0;                                                                                                                                       
(gdb) n
Couldn't get registers: No such process.
(gdb) [Thread 0x7fe36476d6c0 (LWP 131400) exited]
```

Any ideas where to look and how to proceed in order to find what the reason for the issue is are much appreciated.

UPDATE: I've created a simple example based on my real structures and I don't have the issue.  Here's the example:

C code:

```
enum ENUM_TYPE {
    SIMPLE, COMPLEX
};

typedef struct {
    enum ENUM_TYPE ttype;
    int justANumber;
    double justADouble;
} exampleStruct;

typedef struct {
    double funnyDouble;
    exampleStruct twoExamples[2];
} exampleStructsContainer;

typedef struct {
    exampleStructsContainer firstContainer;
    exampleStructsContainer secondContainer;
} manyContainers;

typedef struct {
    int value;
    double timesTwo;
} result;

#include <stdio.h>
#include "struct-struct-array.h"
#include <stdbool.h>


result valueOutOfContainer(manyContainers containers, bool additionalContainer) {
    result r;
    r.value = -1;

    if (additionalContainer) {
        exampleStructsContainer containerNumberTwo = containers.secondContainer;
        printf("Funny double in container number two: %f\n", containerNumberTwo.funnyDouble);
        exampleStruct e = containerNumberTwo.twoExamples[1];
        printf("What's in the double: %f\n", e.justADouble);
        r.value = e.justANumber + 1;
        r.timesTwo = e.justADouble * 2; 
    }
    return r;
}
```

Java Code:

```
@Setter
public class ExampleStruct extends Structure implements Structure.ByValue {

    public int ttype;
    public int justANumber;
    public double justADouble;

    @Override
    protected List<String> getFieldOrder() {
        return Arrays.asList("ttype", "justANumber", "justADouble");
    }
}

@Setter
public class ExampleStructsContainer extends Structure implements Structure.ByValue {

    public double funnyDouble;
    public ExampleStruct[] twoExamples = new ExampleStruct[2];

    @Override
    protected List<String> getFieldOrder() {
        return Arrays.asList("funnyDouble", "twoExamples");
    }

}


@Setter
public class ManyContainers extends Structure implements Structure.ByValue {

    public ExampleStructsContainer firstContainer;
    public ExampleStructsContainer secondContainer;

    @Override
    protected List<String> getFieldOrder() {
        return Arrays.asList("firstContainer", "secondContainer");
    }

}



@Getter
public class Result extends Structure implements Structure.ByValue {

    public int value;
    public double timesTwo;

    @Override
    protected List<String> getFieldOrder() {
        return Arrays.asList("value", "timesTwo");
    }
}


public interface ExampleService {

    Result test(ManyContainers manyContainers);
}

public class ExampleServiceImpl implements ExampleService {

    private ExampleNativeService exampleNativeService = ExampleNativeService.INSTANCE;
    @Override
    public Result test(ManyContainers manyContainers) {
        return exampleNativeService.valueOutOfContainer(manyContainers, true);
    }
}


public class ExampleServiceImplTest {

    @Test
    void testShouldReturnCorrectResult()  {
        final var myContainers = new ManyContainers();
        myContainers.setFirstContainer(container(example(0, 21, 0.123), example(1, 22, 0.123)));
        myContainers.setSecondContainer(container(example(0, 42, 0.123), example(1, 1335, 3.14)));
        final var exampleService = new ExampleServiceImpl();
        final var r = exampleService.test(myContainers);
        assertThat(r.getValue()).isEqualTo(1336);
        assertThat(r.getTimesTwo()).isEqualTo(6.28);
    }

    private ExampleStructsContainer container(ExampleStruct e1, ExampleStruct e2) {
        final var exampleList = new ArrayList<ExampleStruct>();
        exampleList.add(e1);
        exampleList.add(e2);
        final var eContainer = new ExampleStructsContainer();
        eContainer.setTwoExamples(exampleList.toArray(ExampleStruct[]::new));
        eContainer.setFunnyDouble(4.3);
        return eContainer;
    }

    private ExampleStruct example(int t, int num, double d) {
        final var e = new ExampleStruct();
        e.setTtype(t);
        e.setJustANumber(num);
        e.setJustADouble(d);
        return e;
    }

}
```

I think that that means, the problem is somewhere in my original code.

Comment: `prev_size (next_chunk (p)))` possibly error in linked list. How do you know next_chunk is valid?

Comment: Do you have a complete stacktrace before the libc.so call? Please provide a [minimal reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: @aled I don't get a stacktrace from Java at all. and the backtrace that I got from gdb goes back to jvm, and not to my code. I've updated my post with a minimal example, unfortunately, I don't get the problem with the example.

Comment: @stark I don't have a linked list in my code and I'm not sure if next_chunk is valid. I guess p points to some invalid memory.

Comment: @al. I mean from the native stacktrace you got a single for libc.so. When the JVM can it generates a full native/Java stacktrace. Did you got an hs_err_PID.log file with more details?

Comment: no, no stacktrace in the logs. the snippet is all I got from the logs.

Answer (score 1):

Without seeing your Java implementation it's difficult to precisely identify the cause, but the error from the native side makes it clear you're dealing with native memory that you do not own:

```
Thread 2 "Test worker" received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x00007fe3948420ef in unlink_chunk (p=p@entry=0x7fe38caedbe0, av=0x7fe38c000030) at malloc.c:1604
1604      if (chunksize (p) != prev_size (next_chunk (p)))
```

That points to this code:

```c
* Take a chunk off a bin list.  */
static void
unlink_chunk (mstate av, mchunkptr p)
{
  if (chunksize (p) != prev_size (next_chunk (p)))
    malloc_printerr ("corrupted size vs. prev_size");
```

Those macros eventually call `(p)->mchunk_size` and `(p)->mchunk_prev_size`; but it's likely that the Java process does not own the memory associated with `p`, thus the crash.  Possibly you've already freed it, or possibly `p` came from some group of bytes it wasn't supposed to.

Debugging this requires following the Java/JNA-side and native-side allocation of the memory associated with the native function calls.  If you allocate on the Java side, you have to free on the Java side; if you allocate on the native side, you use the appropriate native API to free that allocation.  You may be doing both.

A common issue with JNA is that the object containing the memory allocation may be come unreachable at some point, and eligible for garbage collection; the native memory is freed as part of that process.  Make sure you retain a strong reference to any Java objects associated with that memory allocation (`Structure` or `Memory`, etc.).

Another potential candidate is stack corruption where you're sending a pointer address from a set of bytes you didn't mean to; this can occur with incorrect type mappings in your native function calls.  This could be the culprit here where the call freeing the memory works on its own, but running other tests with it may corrupt the stack.

With your updated code, another potential problem is the Structure array.  When you instantiated the `ExampleStructsContainer` object, it had a native memory allocation for the structure array which was contiguous.  However, you instantiated the individual array elements separately yourself, so the Java-side objects did not have the same native memory as the structure.  Combined with the missing fields you indicated in your self-answer, this could also have been a contributing factor.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I've gone through my implementation, and I don't do any memory allocation from either side. I also created a simple example (posted in my original question), to check if the mapping works, and I had n problem at all. Everything is passed by value, and the array that I pass to C is a fixed size array.

I also suspect something with the garbage collect, since the original issue doesn't occur when I run the test separately. What do you mean by "strong reference"?

Comment: The JNA memory allocation backs the `Structure` as I indicated.  Since you allocated the wrong amount and passed it to native, and native expected more bytes, I expect this is the point where undefined behavior started.  As for a "strong reference" that means making sure the Java object is referenced after the Native call is done with it, or using a `ReachabilityFence`.

Comment: @al. the problem is this assignment: `eContainer.setTwoExamples(exampleList.toArray(ExampleStruct[]::new))`.  When you declared the `ExampleStructsContainer` it internally allocated contiguous memory for the two `ExampleStruct` objects.  However, when you created the new objects individually in a list, they had their own memory allocation that was not the same as the structure's.  You should use the `Structure.toArray()` method to allocate contiguous memory for an array of structures. Or you could just declare two individual structures inside the container without using an array.

Comment: let me just see if I understand correctly:

The line in ExampleStructsContainer:
   `public ExampleStruct[] twoExamples = new ExampleStruct[2];`
allocates contiguous memory.

if that is the case I don't understand why I get `java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Bounds exceeds available space : size=16, offset=32` when I create a contiguous array in the test method, fill it with constant values and pass it to the member's setter. Is this because I need to copy the memory of the newly created contiguous array to the one in the ExampleStructsContainer class?

Comment: @al. `new ExampleStruct[2];` doesn't allocate anything by itself, it's an array of (typed) null... but when the containing structure is instantiated with `new ExampleStructsContainer()`, JNA calculates the memory requirements for a `double` and two `ExampleStruct` objects and allocates that. Each of those has two `int`s and a `double` for 16 bytes, so `ExampleStructsContainer` is now backed by a native 8 + 16 + 16 = 40 byte `Memory` buffer.  However, when you instantiate the inner structs separately with `new ExampleStruct()` they each have their own 16 byte allocations elsewhere in memory...

Comment: @al. So you should allocate the structure array contiguously using `toArray()`. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63781502/1161484) for an example.  `ExampleStruct[] twoExamples = (ExampleStruct[]) new ExampleStruct().toArray(2);`

Answer (score 0):

I was able to overcome the issue, found some missing fields in the result struct mapping. These fields however were initialized in the C code. My explanation is that the memory for these fields could not be freed, or reallocated because it wasn't owned by JNA.

Comment: Yes, you declared the temporary `r` variable on the native side and then sent it (or a pointer to it, technically) to Java without a persistent native allocation.  So any later reference to any element of the Structure on the Java side was touching native memory that wasn't allocated.  The standard pattern for results like this is to declare the Result structure on the Java side and pass it as an argument; the native side can then fill the values in it.  Please see my other comment/answer about your structure array allocation as well.

Comment: `So any later reference to any element of the Structure on the Java side was touching native memory that wasn't allocated.` 

Outside of the Java method where I'm calling the native method or also inside it? 

Because atm I don't get any problems, when I use the Result object directly in the method, where I'm calling the native method. I'm aware that this doesn't mean that my implementation is correct from a memory pov.

Comment: It's a bit hard to follow where the problem actually is or isn't using your sample code (which works).  I'm making assumptions that the real code may not be as simple or have such convenient assignments (I think your `ManyStructures` individual assignment may actually "fix" the earlier problem when it gets created but I suspect it's not actually defined as two single element structures....)